# executing spark job using sparksubmitoperator but getting error

Tags: python, pyspark, airflow

```
*** Found local files:
***   * /home/priteshs/airflow/logs/dag_id=Execute_SparkJob_with_spark_operator/run_id=manual__2023-06-27T06:13:27.403173+00:00/task_id=spark_submit_task/attempt=7.log
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {taskinstance.py:1125} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: Execute_SparkJob_with_spark_operator.spark_submit_task manual__2023-06-27T06:13:27.403173+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {taskinstance.py:1125} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: Execute_SparkJob_with_spark_operator.spark_submit_task manual__2023-06-27T06:13:27.403173+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {taskinstance.py:1331} INFO - Starting attempt 7 of 7
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {taskinstance.py:1350} INFO - Executing <Task(SparkSubmitOperator): spark_submit_task> on 2023-06-27 06:13:27.403173+00:00
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 57829 to run task
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'Execute_SparkJob_with_spark_operator', 'spark_submit_task', 'manual__2023-06-27T06:13:27.403173+00:00', '--job-id', '1051', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/sparkOperator.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp9kkot82v']
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 1051: Subtask spark_submit_task
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: Execute_SparkJob_with_spark_operator.spark_submit_task manual__2023-06-27T06:13:27.403173+00:00 [running]> on host E14-5
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {taskinstance.py:1568} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='priteshsurale' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='Execute_SparkJob_with_spark_operator' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='spark_submit_task' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-06-27T06:13:27.403173+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='7' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2023-06-27T06:13:27.403173+00:00'
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'spark_local' for task execution.
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {taskinstance.py:1847} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/priteshs/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 156, in execute
    self._hook = self._get_hook()
  File "/home/priteshs/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py", line 165, in _get_hook
    return SparkSubmitHook(
  File "/home/priteshs/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 154, in __init__
    self._connection = self._resolve_connection()
  File "/home/priteshs/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py", line 209, in _resolve_connection
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: The `spark-home` extra is not allowed any more. Please make sure one of ['spark-submit', 'spark2-submit', 'spark3-submit'] is available on the PATH, and set `spark-binary` if needed.
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {taskinstance.py:1368} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=Execute_SparkJob_with_spark_operator, task_id=spark_submit_task, execution_date=20230627T061327, start_date=20230627T085052, end_date=20230627T085052
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {standard_task_runner.py:104} ERROR - Failed to execute job 1051 for task spark_submit_task (The `spark-home` extra is not allowed any more. Please make sure one of ['spark-submit', 'spark2-submit', 'spark3-submit'] is available on the PATH, and set `spark-binary` if needed.; 57829)
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {local_task_job_runner.py:232} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-06-27, 14:20:52 IST] {taskinstance.py:2674} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

while executing sparkjob using sparksubmit operator i got this error i unable to resolve this error.

this is my code i have also added spark submit file path to os.environ and not getting what to change and what to edit :( i have stuck in this problem from so many days!

```
import os                                                                   # os 
import sys                                                                  # system    
sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())                                             # add current working directory to system path 
from airflow import DAG                                                     # airflow DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta                                    # datetime and timedelta    
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator   # spark operator
from airflow.models import Variable                                   # airflow variable
pyspark_app_home=Variable.get("PYSPARK_APP_HOME")
os.environ['PATH'] = '/home/priteshs/Downloads/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/bin:' + os.environ['PATH']


default_args = { 
            'owner': 'priteshsurale',
            'depends_on_past': False,
            'start_date': datetime(2023, 5, 24),
            'retries': 1,
            'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
        }


spark_config = {
    'conf':{
        "spark.jars": "/home/priteshs/Downloads/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/postgresql-42.6.0.jar,/home/priteshs/Downloads/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar",
        "spark.executor.extraClassPath": "/home/priteshs/Downloads/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/postgresql-42.6.0.jar:/home/priteshs/Downloads/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar",
        "spark.driver.extraClassPath": "/home/priteshs/Downloads/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/postgresql-42.6.0.jar:/home/priteshs/Downloads/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/jars/hadoop-aws-3.3.2.jar"
    },
    'conn_id': 'spark_local',
    'application': pyspark_app_home + '/sparkJob.py',
    'driver_memory': '2g',
    'executor_memory': '4g',
    'executor_cores': 1,
    'num_executors': 1,
    'spark_binary': '/home/priteshs/Downloads/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3/bin/spark-submit'
    }


with DAG(dag_id='Execute_SparkJob_with_spark_operator', catchup=False, schedule='0 12 * * *', default_args=default_args, tags=['SparkSubmitOperator']) as dag:
    
    spark_submit_task = SparkSubmitOperator(
        task_id='spark_submit_task',    
        **spark_config
    )
```

given path to spark_binary is correct and absolute path

and for conn_id i set like this [image]